# Laptop speakers dont work

Tags: sound

I cannot hear the sound any more on my laptop, I get only dummy-output on my audio device.
Who can help me? Ubuntu 12.10 is installed.

Comment: What kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: Adding to @Alvar can you hear anything if you plug in headphones?